# Not accessing function in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently trying to access a function on another file.(another layer, to be more precise).

Both layers are on a scene.

Third layer is trying to get a function from first layer...

Here's how I'm doing this:

Here's my scene in scene.h

```
 #import "firstLayer.h"
 #import "secondLayer.h"
 #import "thirdLayer.h"

@interface myScene : CCScene
{
// custom instance vars here...
}
@end
```

Here's how I cast my scene in scene.m

```
-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self != nil){

firstLayer *firstLayerz = [firstLayer node];
    [firstLayerz setTag:111];
    [self addChild:firstLayerz z:0];


    secondLayer *secondLayerz = [secondLayer node];
    [secondLayer setTag:112];
    [self addChild:secondLayer z:2];


    thirdLayer *thirdLayerz = [thirdLayer node];
    [thirdLayerz setTag:113];
    [self addChild:thirdLayerz z:4];
```

Here's how I cast the function in thirdLayer.m

```
#import "scene.h"

@implementation thirdLayer.m

-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self != nil){

     firstLayer* firstLayerz = (firstLayer*)[self.parent getChildByTag:111];

     [firstLayerz functionNeeded];

}
```

Here's functionNeeded in firstLayer.m (right below init(

```
    -(void)functionNeeded {
NSLog(@"inside fnnction needed");
}
```

Of course the log ain't showing...

I do the proper cast in firstLayer.h

```
 @interface firstLayer : CCLayer {

 }


-(void)functionNeeded;


@end
```

Comment: What part of this is C++?

Comment: is firstLayerz nil? If so check that self.parent is the node containing the first layer and not some other node (self perhaps)

Comment: I guess you are getting the wrong type of object from self.parent

Comment: Did you try [super methodName]; ??

Comment: Im sorry, I clicked the wrong tag. Its Ob-C,  when I Log the instance, it actually gives me (null) so Im guessing the function access something it hasn't been created??

Answer (score 1):

In your firstLayer's init method write

```
self.tag = 111;
```

Now in your ThirdLayer where you want to call method of first layer write :

```
CCScene *current = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
if (current) {
   id layer = [current getChildByTag:111];
   if (layer) {
      [layer functionNeeded];
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend doing that once as a globalClass variable or doing it just each time I call it?(if Im calling it a lot of times, would you still recommend it?) Im going to try that about now.

Comment: I tried what you told me, I did a Log inside each if and nothing's happening. I did a log on current and its returning Null.
I did add self.tag  in firstLayer init method.....If it helps, my scene.h doesnt have anything inside the interface nor on the outside haha

Comment: Can you please update this questions with your class's hierarchy? only .h file and if possible then .m file also.

Comment: I think I've updated with the information you need.
If you need anything else Im glad to keep updating!!! Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think, my code is not working because of your firstLayer , secondLayer And ThirdLayer is of CCLayer.

Comment: What would they need to be ??

Comment: If they are of type CCScene, then all the scene will be available in running scene.